# Bash inserting quotes into string before execution

Tags: bash

I have managed to track done a weird problem in an init script I am working on. I have simplified the problem down in the following example:

```
> set -x                           # <--- Make Bash show the commands it runs
> cmd="echo \"hello this is a test\""
+ cmd='echo "hello this is a test"'
> $cmd
+ echo '"hello' this is a 'test"'  # <--- Where have the single quotes come from?
"hello this is a test"
```

Why is bash inserting those extra single quotes into the executed command?

The extra quotes don't cause any problems in the above example, but they are really giving me a headache.

For the curious, the actual problem code is:

```
cmd="start-stop-daemon --start $DAEMON_OPTS \
    --quiet \
    --oknodo \
    --background \
    --make-pidfile \
    $* \
    --pidfile $CELERYD_PID_FILE
    --exec /bin/su -- -c \"$CELERYD $CELERYD_OPTS\" - $CELERYD_USER"
```

Which produces this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --chdir /home/continuous/ci --quiet --oknodo --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/celeryd.pid --exec /bin/su -- -c '"/home/continuous/ci/manage.py' celeryd -f /var/log/celeryd.log -l 'INFO"' - continuous
```

And therefore:

```
/bin/su: invalid option -- 'f'
```

Note: I am using the `su` command here as I need to ensure the user's virtualenv is setup before celeryd is run. `--chuid` will not provide this

Comment: What value you want to achieve (for cmd)?

Comment: I would expect the 5th line in the simple example to be:

`+ echo "hello this is a test"`

(i.e. without the mystery single quotes being added)

Comment: Hmmm, I see now, interesting. +1 (:

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because when you try to execute your command with

```
$cmd
```

only one layer of expansion happens.  `$cmd` contains `echo "hello this is a test"`, which is expanded into 6 whitespace-separated tokens:

1. `echo`
2. `"hello`
3. `this`
4. `is`
5. `a`
6. `test"`

and that's what the `set -x` output is showing you: it's putting single quotes around the tokens that contain double quotes, in order to be clear about what the individual tokens are.

If you want `$cmd` to be expanded into a string which then has all the bash quoting rules applied again, try executing your command with:

```
bash -c "$cmd"
```

or (as @bitmask points out in the comments, and this is probably more efficient)

```
eval "$cmd"
```

instead of just

```
$cmd
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Using `bash -c "$cmd"` did just the trick. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Be very, very wary of any suggestion to use `eval` or command execution via `bash -c`.  You are opening yourself, and users of your script, up to non-obvious security holes.

Answer (score 5):

Use Bash [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374694/prevent-bash-from-adding-single-quotes-to-variable-output) to achieve the behavior you want, without resorting to the very dangerous (see below) `eval` and `bash -c`.

Using arrays:

```
declare -a CMD=(echo --test-arg \"Hello\ there\ friend\")
set -x
echo "${CMD[@]}"
"${CMD[@]}"
```

outputs:

```
+ echo echo --test-arg '"Hello there friend"'
echo --test-arg "Hello there friend"
+ echo --test-arg '"Hello there friend"'
--test-arg "Hello there friend"
```

Be careful to ensure that your array invocation is wrapped by double-quotes; otherwise, Bash tries to perform the same "bare-minimum safety" escaping of special characters:

```
declare -a CMD=(echo --test-arg \"Hello\ there\ friend\")
set -x
echo "${CMD[@]}"
${CMD[@]}
```

outputs:

```
+ echo echo --test-arg '"Hello there friend"'
echo --test-arg "Hello there friend"
+ echo --test-arg '"Hello' there 'friend"'
--test-arg "Hello there friend"
```

### ASIDE: Why is `eval` dangerous?

`eval` is only safe if you can guarantee that every input passed to it will not unexpectedly change the way that the command under `eval` works.

**Example**: As a totally contrived example, let's say we have a script that runs as part of our automated code deployment process.  The script sorts some input (in this case, three lines of hardcoded text), and outputs the sorted text to a file whose named is based on the current directory name.  Similar to the original SO question posed here, we want to dynamically construct the `--output=` parameter passed to sort, but we must (must? not really) rely on `eval` because of Bash's auto-quoting "safety" feature.

```
echo $'3\n2\n1' | eval sort -n --output="$(pwd | sed 's:.*/::')".txt
```

Running this script in the directory `/usr/local/deploy/project1/` results in a new file being created at `/usr/local/deploy/project1/project1.txt`.

So somehow, if a user were to create a project subdirectory named `owned.txt; touch hahaha.txt; echo`, the script would actually run the following series of commands:

```
echo $'3\n2\n1'
sort -n --output=owned.txt; touch hahaha.txt; echo .txt
```

As you can see, that's totally not what we want.  But you may ask, in this contrived example, isn't it unlikely that the user could create a project directory `owned.txt; touch hahaha.txt; echo`, and if they could, aren't we already in trouble already?

Maybe, but what about a scenario where the script is parsing not the current directory name, but instead the name of a remote `git` source code repository branch?  Unless you plan to be extremely diligent about restricting or sanitizing every user-controlled artifact whose name, identifier, or other data is used by your script, stay well clear of `eval`.