# Bash stripping quotes - how to preserve quotes

Tags: java, bash, shell, env

I need to pass cmd parameters to my bash script, but it keeps on stripping out the quotes.

Below is an example. In my script, I add some additional processing where I add data to my first variable before I process the command

```
$> ./test.sh -t some.comman -extraswitch "some addtional info"
```

The script uses Java to do some processing, but the "some additional info" is missing the quotes and thus can't execute the Java portion of this script. How can I preserve the quotes from the command line so that I can execute my Java command in my script?

#### Java command in script

```
java $JAVA_OPTS "$@"
```

**Output**

```
java lib -someoption -anotheroption -javalibswitch some additional info
```

**Intended Output**

```
java lib -someoption -anotheroption -javalibswitch "some additional info"
```

Comment: `$> ./test.sh -t some.comman -extraswitch '"some addtional info"'` should do it

Comment: `"$@"` *will* properly pass the arguments to java. In what way is your java program failing to handle its arguments?

Comment: Please share exactly what you are doing in the script. If you're playing around with the parameters or using a shell function definition, the above command will behave differently.

Comment: Use a backslash `"\"stuff\""`

Comment: Since the invocation you show does not match the `java` command line you claim doesn't work, I think your problem is with `JAVA_OPTS`, no `$@`.

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the quotes? The command line will properly arrange the arguments in your array; what code fails without them?

Comment: I have to call this script via crontab. I have multiple crontab entries that look like my example where i have to pass the full cmd string to java to execut. Im trying to avoid having to hard escape the quotes i.e. "\" on each crontab entry as i would like a more generic way of passing the value including the quotes to java. The quoted portion of this is mostly additional sql that is processed by java and that is why i need to pass the quotes else we will have to have massive rework of our standalone java jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically use single quotes to avoid shell interpolation when you want to quote strings with quotes in them.

```
./test.sh -t some.comman -extraswitch '"some addtional info"'
```

Comment: I would rather have my script take care of the quote instead of me changing all the crontab entries.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The shell strips those quotes before they ever get to the process in which your script is running. If you want a literal quote passed to the script, you must quote the quote.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass argument like this

```
./test.sh -t some.comman -extraswitch \"some addtional info\"
```

Comment: This is definitely a bad answer: `test.sh` will see 6 arguments: `-t` and `some.comman` and `-extraswitch` and `"some` and `addtional` and `info"`.

Comment: You should edit your answer to be: `./test.sh -t some.comman -extraswitch "\"some addtional info\""`

Comment: I have to call this script via crontab. I have multiple crontab entries that look like my example where i have to pass the full cmd string to java to exeute. Im trying to avoid having to hard escape the quotes i.e. "\" on each crontab entry as i would like a more generic way of passing the value including the quotes to java. The quoted portion of this is mostly additional sql that is processed by java and that is why i need to pass the quotes else we will have to have massive rework of our standalone java jobs.