# How do you stop bash from stripping quotes when running a variable as a command?

Tags: bash

I have a command stored in a variable, which I then run:

```
[root@cxpxwly01wel001 init.d]# cat test
#!/bin/bash
command="su - root -c 'java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command'"
echo $command
$command
[root@cxpxwly01wel001 init.d]# ./test
su - root -c 'java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command'
su: invalid option -- 'X'
Try `su --help' for more information.
```

The su error is what you get if the single quotes aren't there:

```
[root@cxpxwly01wel001 init.d]# su - root -c java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command
su: invalid option -- 'X'
Try `su --help' for more information.
```

With the single quotes there the command works as expected:

```
[root@cxpxwly01wel001 init.d]# su - root -c 'java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command'
-bash: java: command not found
```

Which suggests to me that when running the variable as a command the single quotes aren't preserved.  How do I preserve them?

Note:  I'm editing an existing script (inserting the su - around the java command), so I'd like to change as little as possible to keep it close to the source.

---

Let me add the output when run with `set -x`:

```
+ command='su - root -c '\''java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command'\'''
+ echo su - root -c ''\''java' -Xms16m '-the_rest_of_my_java_command'\'''
su - root -c 'java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command'
+ su - root -c ''\''java' -Xms16m '-the_rest_of_my_java_command'\'''
su: invalid option -- 'X'
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique I use to avoid the "quoting inside quotes" issues is to build the command in an array.  For instance, instead of :

```
command="su - root -c 'java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command'"
```

I would use :

```
declare -a command=(su - root -c 'java -Xms16m -the_rest_of_my_java_command')
```

You can still echo the command (with an array expansion) :

```
echo "${command[@]}"
```

Or run it :

```
"${command[@]}"
```

The double quotes around the array expansion are important : they tell the shell to expand items without doing any word splitting, so an item containing whitespace will keep its identity as a single string.

By doing it this way, the last argument, which is inside quotes, will remain a single string, and the `su` command will not see `-Xms16m` as an (invalid) option.

As an aside, the `[@]` in `"${command[@]}"` means "all elements in the array".  Whereas, in an expression like `"${command[1]}"`, `[1]` would mean "only element at index 1".

Comment: `++` for demonstrating how it should be done, also well explained here [BashFAQ-050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: So it has to involve a change at the point where the script is run?  I'm editing part of a much longer script, I really just want to change the command but not change the parts of the script that invoke it.  Currently I'm inclined to make a second script which just calls the original script as the desired user.