# Issues with extra single quote marks when passing variable containing special characters as argument to a command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, command-line-arguments, single-quotes

First of all, thank you all for trying to help out! Unfortunately, so far no solution has been found yet. I am updating the description to make the problem more reproducible.

- **Update1**: use shellcheck.net to clear all other potential issues.
- **Update2**: describe the real use case where we run cmake below.

---

**Section 1: minimal case**

First found the issue with `cmake` but it may not be limited to it, by changing `cmake` in the following minimal reproducible example to `make` or something else could also reproduce the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

run() {
    arg=$1
    printf '%q\n' "$arg"
    cmake "$arg" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
}

TEXT="local -DCMAKE_ARG=\"arg1;arg2\""

CMAKE_OPTS1=$(echo "$TEXT" | awk '/local/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^-D/) {printf "%s ", $i}}}' | tr -d '";')
CMAKE_OPTS2=$(echo "$TEXT" | awk '/local/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^-D/) {printf "%s ", $i}}}' )
CMAKE_OPTS3=("$(echo "$TEXT" | awk '/local/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^-D/) {printf "%s ", $i}}}' )")

run $CMAKE_OPTS1
run $CMAKE_OPTS2
run "${CMAKE_OPTS3[@]}"
```

the print out results are (reducing to the lines of interests)

```
-DCMAKE_ARG=arg1arg2
+ cmake -DCMAKE_ARG=arg1arg2

-DCMAKE_ARG=\"arg1\;arg2\"
+ cmake '-DCMAKE_ARG="arg1;arg2"'

-DCMAKE_ARG=\"arg1\;arg2\"\
+ cmake '-DCMAKE_ARG="arg1;arg2" '
```

Unfortunately, `cmake '-DCMAKE_ARG="arg1;arg2"'` does not work properly.

- *CMAKE_OPTS1* is only used for reference, in this case no special characters present in the variable string, and it seems to be working as expected.
- *CMAKE_OPTS2* is the real case where I wish to pass variable containing special characters as argument to a command. Hence the single marks seem to be interfering with command argument parsing.
- *CMAKE_OPTS3* is what I have found from similar issues on this forum, and it does not work either.

---

**Section 2: original script**

with lots of modification to minimize the script of course. Hence it involves pulling from a docker and a GitHub repo, **both are public and open source**.

First, pull docker from Docker Hub (to ensure necessary clang env):

> docker pull rocm/miopen:ci

Then within the docker, use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

build_miopen_ck() {
    echo "Building Composable Kernel"
    ck_commit=$1
    ck_cmake_opts=$2
    if [ -z "$ck_commit" ]; then
        echo "Composable Kernel entry was not found in requirements.txt"
        return
    fi
    mkdir -p /tmp/composable_kernel && cd /tmp/composable_kernel || exit
    wget -nv "https://www.github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/composable_kernel/archive/${ck_commit}.tar.gz"
    tar -xzf "${ck_commit}.tar.gz"
    cd "composable_kernel-${ck_commit}" || exit
    rm -rf build
    mkdir -p build && cd build || exit
    cmake -DBUILD_DEV=OFF \
          -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
          -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang++" \
          -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang" \
          -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$ROCM_PATH" \
          "${ck_cmake_opts}" \
          ..
    make -j"$(nproc)" install
    echo "Finished building Composable Kernel"
}

TEXT="ROCmSoftwarePlatform/composable_kernel@5f28614222bd590bc31d98838bc019e9c3a7ad45 -DGPU_TARGETS=\"gfx900;gfx906;gfx908;gfx90a;gfx1030;gfx1100;gfx1101;gfx1102\""

CK_COMMIT=$(echo "$TEXT" | awk '/composable_kernel/ {split($1, s, "@"); print s[2]}')
CK_CMAKE_OPTS=$(echo "$TEXT" | awk '/composable_kernel/ {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^-D/) {printf "%s ", $i}}}')

build_miopen_ck "$CK_COMMIT" "$CK_CMAKE_OPTS"
```

Soon (might be a while) the build will fail with the following error:

```
clang-15: error: invalid target ID 'gfx900 --offload-arch=gfx906 --offload-arch=gfx908 --offload-arch=gfx90a --offload-arch=gfx1030 --offload-arch=gfx1100 --offload-arch=gfx1101 --offload-arch=gfx1102'; format is a processor name followed by an optional colon-delimited list of features followed by an enable/disable sign (e.g., 'gfx908:sramecc+:xnack-')
```

and by diagnosing the log, the single quotes look suspecious:

```
cmake -DBUILD_DEV=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= '-DGPU_TARGETS="gfx900;gfx906;gfx908;gfx90a;gfx1030;gfx1100;gfx1101;gfx1102" ' ..
```

if I go to the directory, and re-run cmake with

```
cmake -DBUILD_DEV=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/rocm/llvm/bin/clang -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= -DGPU_TARGETS="gfx900;gfx906;gfx908;gfx90a;gfx1030;gfx1100;gfx1101;gfx1102"  ..
```

then everything works as expected from there.

From the error above, it should have something to do with shell parameter expansion:

- it should read as

```
    '--offload-arch=gfx900' '--offload-arch=gfx906' ...
```

```
but instead, the single quotes are messing up the **secondary** parsing process, and it reads as if it is:
```

```
    '--offload-arch=gfx900 --offload-arch=gfx906 ...'
```

As related to the **minimal example** above, if passing variable containing special characters as argument to a command does not automatically add a pair of single quote, we should not have this secondary parsing issues?

A few experiments so far:

- as recommended by one of the users below, removing `set -x` does not resolve this issue unfortunately :(
- maybe the minimal example above is still a good starting point? Is there a way to avoid adding single quotes? When are they added and how to remove? It's not part of the string itself unfortunately.

**Workaround**:
So far a *working* workaround is to grep the string **after** `-DGPU_TARGETS=`, i.e. instead of `cmake "$arg"` we can make the following work `cmake -DGPU_TARGETS="${subset_arg}"`. However, this is a workaround and the original issue still persists.

Comment: The single-quotes are added by `set -x` to indicate that the argument contains characters that *could* have some special meaning to the shell (i.e. `;`, which is normally a command delimiter), but that in this case the characters are just being passed literally as part of the argument (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087494/bash-inserting-quotes-into-string-before-execution)). I'm not clear exactly what it's supposed to do (what command would run `cmake` the way you want it run here?), but all the non-double-quoted variable references look ripe for problems.

Comment: @GordonDavisson correction from my experiments. No it doesn't resolve the issue with the original script. It seems that when removing `set -x` the single quotes are still passed together with the variable as arguments to cmake :(
I wonder how to set up a minimal reproducible example in this case without set -x

Comment: Removing or adding the `set -x` shouldn't affect what arguments are passed to `cmake`. And, it is hard to believe, from the examples given in the question, that a _literal_ `'` is passed to `cmake` as a part of an argument. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: What I'm asking for is a minimal reproducible example *of running `cmake` correctly*. Never mind the script, storing arguments in variables, etc, just give a command that runs `cmake` the way you want it run (e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_ARG="arg1;arg2"` or whatever).

Comment: As an aside, you may want to read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). But, as I wrote in my previous comment, your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: As the bash tag you used instructs: "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here". Fix the issues it tells you about then post the corrected code and let us know if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add backslash doubled :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

run() {
    arg="$1"
    printf '%q\n' "$arg"
    cmake "$arg" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
}

TEXT="local -DCMAKE_ARG=arg1;arg2"

CMAKE_OPTS="${TEXT#local }" # Remove [local ]
CMAKE_OPTS="${CMAKE_OPTS//;/\\\\;}" # Add \ doubled
run "$CMAKE_OPTS"

# If four backslashes (\\\\) don't work, try two (\\)
```

Comment: Bash treats escapes (and quotes) in variables as plain data, not shell syntax, so adding escapes/quotes to variables is only useful if they're going through an extra level of parsing for some reason -- and that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson cmake passes `CMAKE_ARG` to other commands, that's why OP had problems with `;` in the first place.